# Delphi Use variables for property

Tags: delphi

I am having a little issue with getting a variable in a property.

This is the original working code:

```
// Note: "b1" is the name of the component in this case a TChromium component.

MainForm.b1.Browser.MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScript
```

I need to insert a variable instead of the name so I did this:

```
MainForm.'+myVariable+'.Browser.MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScript
```

The above is giving me an error:

> [dcc32 Error] main.pas(225): E2029 Identifier expected but string constant found

What I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `MainForm.myVariable.Browser.MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScript`

Comment: You can use `FindComponent('ComponentName')` to get component instance by name. But I would rather prepare a collection of *known* component instances.

Comment: I'm passing the variable name through a procedure ... myproc(myVariable:string);

Comment: You need some way to get an object reference from a string. Only someone with understanding of the program can work out the best way to do that. If you can avoid needing to do this at all it would be better. What makes you feel you have to refer to an object by name?

Comment: Thers multiple object names and it might grow, so as I'm in a loop I thought the easiest way would be to pass the object name otherwise I would have to repeat the same code for each one. I didn't realize it was going to be a problem

Comment: You should ask yourself whether you really do want to refer to controls by name. It is something to be avoided if possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you can have multiple instances, and they can grow, rather keep them in a list.

```
TChromium(FList.Items[I]).Browser.MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScript;
```

This means you would also need to add them at run-time:

```
FList.Add(TChromium.Create(...));
```

You'll need to think about how you choose which instances to use in different situations. E.g. You could have a page control where each page is linked to a particular `TChromium` instance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function I use from time to time.  This returns a flat list of all subcomponents in a tree :

```
Function GetAllRecursive(var AList : TList<TComponent>; 
                             AParent : TComponent) : TList<TComponent>;
var
  i: integer;
Begin
   If AParent = nil Then begin
     result := AList;
     Exit;
   end else
     AList.Add(AParent);
   for i := 0 to AParent.ComponentCount - 1 do
     GetAllRecursive(AList, AParent.Components[i]);
   result := AList;
End;
```

You can modify this to get only `TChromium` components or you can filter through it later, for example :

```
//in type definition 
private    
  FComponents : TList<TComponent>;
  FChromiums : TList<TChromium>;
  //... etc

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var 
  cpt : TComponent;
begin
  FComponents := TList<TComponent>.Create;
  FChromiums := TList<TChromium>.Create;
  GetAllRecursive(FComponents, self);
  for cpt in FComponents do 
    if cpt is TChromium then FChromiums.Add(cpt as TChromium);
end;
```

which you can then use later as

```
for cpt in FChromiums do ExecuteJS(cpt);
```

with

```
procedure TForm1.ExecuteJS(AChromium: TChromium);
begin
  AChromium.Browser.MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScript;
end;
```